# pass additional input with a fileinput in laravel controller

Tags: laravel

I have the follow data in my view file:

```
<form id='foto'  action='photo' method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   @csrf
  <img  src="/images/blank.png" width=60px class="img-circle img-offline img-responsive img-profile"  onclick="fileInput.click();"/>
   <div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden"> <input type="file" accept=".jpg" id="fileInput" name="fileInput" onchange="this.form.submit()"/></div>
   <input type='hidden' name='photo_id' id='photo_id' value='1234' > 
    </form>
```

In my controller I have:

```
 function photo(Request $req)
   {
      $directory_name="public/".Auth::user()->id;
      $identifica=$req->file('photo_id');
       echo $identifica;
      $req->file('fileInput')->storeAs($directory_name,$identifica.".jpg");

 }
```

The upload image is stored as `.jpg`, because the `$req->file('photo_id')` or `=$req->get('photo_id')` is empty but must have a value=1234

How I do to get the value that comes from input `photo_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change like this

```
$identifica=$req->file('photo_id');
```

to

```
$identifica=$req->photo_id;
```